# Get real predicted values from GLM

Tags: r, glm

I am running GLM with linear regression, then i am using predict to fit the response on my test data, but the problem is i am getting the probabilities and i don't know how to convert those probabilities to real values.

```
log<- glm(formula=stock_out_duration~lag_2_market_unres_dos+lag_2_percentage_bias_forecast_error + forecast,train_data_final,family = inverse.gaussian(link = "log"),maxit=100)
summary(log)


predict <- predict(log, test_data, type = 'response')

table_mat <- table(test_data$stock_out_duration)
table_mat
```

Comment: What do you mean "real values"?

Comment: I am predicting the duration of stock out for a particular drug.
So my real values should be 12days, 15days, etc.

Comment: You are misinformed, GLM returns odds, not classes. You need a classification algorithm.

Comment: what does the data look like for `stock_out_duration` e.g. is it a numeric series where 1 = 1 day?

Comment: Stock out duration is a numeric column with values like 12, 17, 4 etc which id the duration of the stock out for a particular drug

Comment: This is a legitimate question. I can use a `factor` as my dependent variable in `glm`, say, with categories "red" and "blue", for, say a logit regression. I then want to generate predictions where I want my prediction to be either "red" or "blue". In practice I can convert from the probabilities returned by `predict` with "response" (or also `fitted`) using a rule of probability > 0.5 to decide between "red" and "blue", but it would be nice if there were a single function that did this in one step. As far as I'm aware, you need to manually do this translation yourself. But I'm not an r expert

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a magic function that does this for you given that you're using `glm`. As you've noted, what typically gets returned is the probabilities. You can convert the probabilities into predictions for the outcome of the underlying categories by choosing the outcome with the largest probability. I agree a one-line function for this would be nice though.

You can get this functionality if use the `glmnet` package.

```
library(glmnet)
y = ifelse(rnorm(100) > 0, "red", "blue")
y = factor(y)
x = rnorm(100)
fit = glmnet(x, y, family="binomial") # use family="multinomial" if there are more than 2 categories in your factor
yhat = predict(fit, newx=x, type="class", s=0)
```

`yhat` in the above will be a vector containing either `"red"` or `"blue"`.

Note, the `type="class"` is the bit that gets you the category outcomes returned in `yhat`. The `s=0` means to use a lambda penalty of zero for the coefficients you use to get predictions. You indicated in the question that you were just doing ordinary regression without any ridge or lasso style penalty factors, so `s=0` ensures you get that in your predictions.